# VirtualBox ping OK but browse NOK

Tags: virtualbox, plesk

I install plesk on my virtualbox as describe here
https://docs.plesk.com/fr-FR/obsidian/deployment-guide/78020/

I create a virtual box ethernet adapter, and activate it for my pleskVM .

On the host (windows) ipconfig show well the ethernet card VirtualBoxon 192.168.240.1 (see file attached) ping is ok

On the VM, ifconfig show the 127.0.0.1 and 10.0.2.15 (see file attached) ping is OK

And when I try to browse 192.168.240.1:8443 it doesn't work...
And don't have anything in logs...
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was missing the port redirection 
check that video https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=217&v=hXGjulTRwKE&feature=emb_logo